# issue in gmail logout in android studio

Tags: java, android

i have integrated gmail login for my android app.
there is a login screen which goes to some activity on login success.
there is an option to go to my account where there is a logout button.
the code for that button is.

```
 GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //for gmail logout
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), gso);
        //ends

}
```

then i setup the onclick listener for the button which calls below method
code-

```
               sessionManager.setLogin(false);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

                mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MyAccountActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                
                                finish();

                                Intent in = new Intent(MyAccountActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);

                                //after pressing back button it wouldn't take to previous task and instead close the app
                                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                startActivity(in);
                            }
                        });
```

it shows the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.signOut()' on a null object reference
```

someone with the solution...?

Comment: As the errpor your **mGoogleSignInClient** is null on button click. Do one thing cut all the code from onStart method and place it on onCreate.

Comment: i earlier had that portion of code in onCreate method but there also it gave me the same error so i placed it in onStart and still getting the same issue

Comment: please attach the whole activity file to review more.

Comment: cant do that it has some company code and mGoogleSignInClient portion is creating the error. no problem in other portion of code

Comment: try to add finish() after the startActivity(in); , It will help you

Comment: did it still showing call on null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
//for gmail logout
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                   .requestEmail()
                   .build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), gso);
//ends
```

This portion of code was not accessible in another method which I was using for logout. So I had to move this portion from `onStart` to that logout method and voilà! It works.

And declare the `GoogleSignInClient` as `final`.